# What is the memory overhead of spawning a Dart isolate?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I've read that the memory overhead for spawning a Dart isolate is ~2.5mb. However, the source for that number is a dartlang.org Google Group discussion, not an official doc. Plus, I can't find the page anymore, I can only find a cached version of it [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:IMvsMy4Yh8EJ:https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/NGHcDh_9MUg+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).

Is ~2.5mb still the memory overhead for each isolate that is spawned?

Comment: The uncached version: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/NGHcDh_9MUg FYI, Florian is on the Dart team so that is pretty good answer for the time. Hopefully it is out of date though and things have improved since 2 years ago.

Comment: Thank you for the link and for letting me know Florian's on the team. I also hope the number is out of date.

Comment: Surely this could be fairly readily determined empirically?

Comment: Testing with Observatory shows that a new Isolate seems to use ~5MB of memory. Manually measuring the memory used by dart.exe also shows the same 5MB jump when using an Isolate. Hopefully I am doing something wrong because it would be very disappointing if the overhead has gotten worse, not better.

Comment: @PixelElephant Is this in checked or unchecked mode? (No idea if there is a difference)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Good question. That was in checked mode. Unchecked is slightly better, ~0.5MB less. So ~4.5MB for an isolate unchecked, and ~5MB checked.